# Handling large array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have an array of English words that is about 275,000 elements long that I need to use for my iOS app written in Swift. However, Xcode doesn't seem to be able to handle such a large (3+ MB) file. The file will not open in Xcode, and when I attempt to compile the app, it seems to compile indefinitely and never build.

How should I handle this large amount of data?

Comment: How about put it in a file and read it at runtime

Comment: @ukim how would I do that?

Comment: 3MB is not large (a single image might be much larger). There should be no difficulty here. Please _show your code_. Or even just a screenshot. Give us at least _some_ idea of what you're doing. Thank you.

Comment: You should looking at Core Data and load it dynamically at runtime. Creating a 275k-element array takes both CPU time and memory space.

Comment: @matt tell Xcode that. I'm not even running any code yet. Simply adding the file to the scope of my project makes the application unresponsive.

Comment: What does "adding the file to the scope of my project" mean? I have a feeling it means dragging the file into the project navigator, but please be explicit.

Comment: @matt File > Add Files To "Project Name" > Add

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce any difficulty with that. You will have to explain better what unusual thing you are doing.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768971/compiling-large-array-literal-in-xcode-8-2. I cannot dupehammer as I already wasted my close vote.

Comment: @CodeDifferent That's overkill. For one, 3 MB is trivially small, even for a phone/watch. Simply loading a txt file at runtime would suffice.

Comment: If you are trying to add a huge array of text as a Swift source file, say that. We all assumed that you were trying to add a .txt file that your code would open and read.

Answer (score 6):

Don't put a huge literal array in your swift source code.

Instead, create a text file, drag that into your project as a resource, then open that and convert it into an array at runtime using `components(separatedBy:)`.

For speed and storage efficiency you could instead write a conversion utility that reads your text file and uses `components(separatedBy:)` to convert it to an `Array` of `Strings`. Then you could write the array of `Strings` to a binary plist.

You could then drag the plist file into your project as a resource, and write code that reads the plist file into an `Array` at launch.

Answer (score 1):

How about put it in a file and read it at runtime? For example, put the elements in the a JSON array and store the array in a text file. Drag the file into your Xcode project, then it will be copied into the app bundle during compilation. Read the JSON array from the file and parse it at runtime.

There are many Tutorial on the internet about reading files in bundle and parse JSON data.

Comment: @matt I thought he meant he was putting the array in Swift code, so he could not compile it.